# How to release objects associated via objc_setAssociatedObject?

Tags: objective-c

If I use a category which uses `objc_setAssociatedObject` to add pseudo-properties to an object, how can I make sure they get released properly? Do I have to release them manually in `dealloc` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The behavior you assign determines how the memory is managed for the type. If you choose retain or copy the object will be released when the instance of the class you add the associated reference to is deallocated. That makes retain and copy behavior operations preferred for Objective-C classes. Assign is also useful to avoid retain cycles as long as you set the reference to nil when done with the object.

> **Constants** 
>   **OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN** Specifies a weak reference to the
>   associated object. 
>   **OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC** Specifies a
>   strong reference to the associated object, and that the association is
>   not made atomically. 
>   **OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC** Specifies that
>   the associated object is copied, and that the association is not made
>   atomically. 
>   **OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN** Specifies a strong reference to
>   the associated object, and that the association is made atomically.
>   **OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY** Specifies that the associated object is copied,
>   and that the association is made atomically.

Comment: That was fast :) but it is not the answer I was looking for. I should have been more specific in my question, sry.

Comment: @radiospiel I stated that above, retain or copy will release the object for you "the object will be released when the class you add the associated reference to is released"

Comment: shouldn't your answer read "the object will be released when the *object* you add the associated reference to is deallocated" instead of "... when the class you add...". This is how I understand apple's doc, meanwhile.

Comment: @radiospiel I change the terminology to the instance of the class

Answer (score 4):

Although you answered your own question, still, since you didn't include the docs text itself, and the page you linked to is no longer available, here it is for convenience of others:

From Apple's Objective-C Runtime Reference

> `void objc_removeAssociatedObjects(id object)`
>
> Removes all associations for a given object.
>
> The main purpose of this function is to make it easy to return an
>   object to a "pristine state”. You should not use this function for
>   general removal of associations from objects, since it also removes
>   associations that other clients may have added to the object.
>   **Typically you should use `objc_setAssociatedObject` with a nil value to
>   clear an association.**